# child recyclerview not scrolling when i put horizontal recyclerview inside another horizontal recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a nested recyclerview and both have a horizontal linear layout but the child one is not scrolling
All consequences 
1) I'm using a snap helper in the parent recyclerview
2) also using recycler view pool in child recyclerview

Answer (score 1):

It is bad practice to use a Nested RecyclerView with the same LayoutManager.
If horizontal scrolling is important to use for you then try `RecyclerView` inside `ViewPager`.

This will behave like this:
When scrolling `RecyclerView`, Fragment will stick to port until `RecyclerView` last item is shown. After that the next fragment switchs.